# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DeprecationDict' on <module 'sklearn.utils.deprecation'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DeprecationDict' on

pickle.load(open(model, 'rb'))

pickle.load(open(model, 'rb'))